# Popover does not get anchored to the triggering element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So my `Twitter Bootstrap` `popovers` seem to be positionally challenged when the triggering element is contained within an element with the style `-ms-overflow-y: auto;` (a scrollable element within the window).

When the element is scrolled, the popover does not scroll with it.

I would really like the popover to move with the content within this scrollable element.  How can I achieve this?

popover code:

```
$(this).popover({
            animation: false,
            html: true,
            placement: popover.placement || 'auto bottom',
            title: popover.title,
            content: popover.validationMessage + popover.content,
            trigger: 'manual',
            container: '.content-panel'
}).click(function (e) {
                $('BUTTON[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function (index, element) { $(this).popover('hide'); });
                $(this).popover('show');
                $('#' + $(this).attr('data-for')).focus();
            });
```

> > `.content-panel` is the scrollable element.

### fiddle me this, Batman

http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/171/

### Update

I would like the popover to continue floating overtop the other elements.  When using `position:relative;` on the parent element it contains the popover instead of letting it float over top.

#### Bad

[image: I don't like this]

#### Good

[image: I do like this]

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Would love to, but I can't seem to get jsfiddle to show a popover.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/VUZhL/ e.g

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your answer @A.Wolff.  It was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parent element (offsetParent) of popover need to **not be** `static`, you could postionned it relatively to document:

`position: relative;`

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/172/)

**EDIT:** for your use case, you could bind `onscroll` event of container and use following snippet:

[SEE jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/174/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').popover();
    $('div').on('scroll', function () {
        var $container = $(this);
        $(this).find('.popover').each(function () {
            $(this).css({
                top:  - $container.scrollTop()
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That does exactly what I asked for - but it has the effect of positioning the popover *inside* the container.  So now it looks all squished and narrow.  Is it possible to have the popover float outside of the container and still be able to scroll with the content?

Comment: So i'm sorry but i didn't understand 'exactly' what you are looking for.

Comment: The javascript solution set me on the right path.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For BS 3 and above

you can use `container: $(element)`

Example:

```
let elem = $(this)
$(elem).popover({
    selector: '[rel=popover]',
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: $(elem),
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    content: 'Popover Content'
});
```