# Boostrap popover not sticking inside modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, popover

The problem is when I use popover outside the modal, it functions as expected, when you scroll down, popover it sticking to its element that triggers the popover.

But when I use it inside the modal, the problem start from there, it is not sticking to element thats trigger the popover.
I'm initializing popover with this code.
Please refer to this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jmvtrinidad/gxn8o2hm/4/).

```
    $('#popover1').popover({
      container: "body",
      html: true,
      content: function () {
        return '<div class="popover-message">' + $(this).data("message") + '</div>';
      }
    });
```

Comment: I am unable to understand , exactly what you want? Can you please explain little bit more

Comment: see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605861/popover-does-not-get-anchored-to-the-triggering-element

Comment: @Ajay Malhotra, he doesn't want the popover to move when he scrolls the page. He wants it anchored to the button.

Comment: Hi @CallumGlennBrankin, It seems the solution is expensive, because it is attached on scroll. What do you think, is this a bug from Bootstrap Version 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [container](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options) config to your modal.

i.e. `container: $('#myModal')`.

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/gxn8o2hm/7/