# Bootstrap popover in fixed nav on wide page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using fixed bootstrap responsive navigation on a page with fixed width container, i.e. on small devices page itself has a horizontal scroll, but navigation adopts to a page width.

One of the buttons in navigation has a popover. The problem is: popover is rendered incorrectly or completely disappears when you scroll main page to the right.

HTML

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#dummy1">Dummy 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#dummy2">Dummy 2</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#contact" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="click" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Contact Popover</a>
                </li>             
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Dummy 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 1700px;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nnxfk7s6/8/

- Run snippet
- Press "Contact Popover" to see the popover
- Scroll page to the right
- Press "Contact Popover" again to see not fully rendered popover

I tried to play with `container` and `viewport` properties of the popover, but it did not resolve a problem. (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)

Comment: I suspect you might need to handle this with `onscroll` have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22606657

Comment: @hammus thanks for the suggestion, that question is about vertical position, but probably it can be adopted to horizontal as well. will try this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with a little bit of javascript code to adjust popover position.

- we need to set popover trigger to `manual`
- we have to set `width` or `min-width` for popover itself
- we know that small arrow position above popover is always correct, we can use arrow offset to calculate correct popover position

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    $('body').on("click", '[data-toggle="popover"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).attr('aria-describedby')) {
          $(this).popover("show");
          // aria-describedby attribute keeps id of the popover
          var $pop = $('#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby'));
          if($pop) {
            // find arrow element within popover to obtain its offset
            var $arrow = $pop.find('.arrow');
            // set new left position for the popover
            $pop.css('left', $arrow.offset().left - $pop.width()*0.75);
            // set new arrow position
            $arrow.css('left', '75%');
          }
        } else {
            $(this).popover("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nnxfk7s6/9/